# getting memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
NSDictionary *headerFields = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response allHeaderFields]; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://secure.tesco.com/clubcard/clubcard/main.asp"];
    NSArray *theCookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:headerFields forURL:url];

   self.mHeaderResponseData= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [theCookies objectAtIndex:2]];
```

mHeaderResponseData having retain property ...

this code is inside `connectionDidRecievResponse` method

any idea ...
and i am releasing mHeaderResponseData in dealloc

Comment: Why do you think there's a leak ? What about the surrounding code ? What does Instruments say ?

Comment: And BTW, you should accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: I agree with @DarkDust there isn't any memory leak here. Perhaps you should check with Instruments and find the specific place where you are getting the memory leak.

Comment: CFHTTPCookieGetCreateDate is deprecated in this OS build.  Clients must call CFHTTPCookieGetCreationTime or the NS equivalent instead or risk leaks.
showing warning in console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you alloc and initialize mHeaderResponseData variable in other functions also or not.

if yes then you need to release it when you are doing stringWithFormat:

and

This line will create mHeaderResponseData without incrementing the retain count.

```
self.mHeaderResponseData= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [theCookies objectAtIndex:2]];
```

so instead use initWithFormat:

Comment: pawan said that the `mHeaderResponseData` property does have `retain` set, so the assignment will correctly increase/decrease retain counts.

Comment: CFHTTPCookieGetCreateDate is deprecated in this OS build.  Clients must call CFHTTPCookieGetCreationTime or the NS equivalent instead or risk leaks.
in console i am getting this warning ???..